# Rename column mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm just trying to rename a column following the documentation, I tried a couple of statements but nothing yet.

Total to price:

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE order RENAME COLUMN  total TO price;
```

But didn't work.

Comment: Which MariaDB version are you using?`

Comment: 10.3.34    I just found it works with CHANGE but don't know what the RENAME is for then.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#rename-column

Comment: Thank you, so it's not in my version.

Comment: the RENAME COLUMN syntax is a new feature of MariaDB 10.5, it is not supported by the version 10.3.34 you are working with

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your are using a version below 10.5

```
ALTER TABLE order CHANGE COLUMN total TO price;
```